# Finding the average of a variable belonging to an object in a BST?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am very new to cpp and am currently facing the following problem.

I have csv file filled with Person object class which I need to insert into my BST.

```
class Person{
        string name;
        string job;
        int age;
}
```

I have successfully populated my BST with this Person object. I now need to calculate the average age of all the Persons in the BST (there is an appropriate getter method for the age).

I have the following as my inorder traversal (with function pointers)

```
template <class T>
void Bst<T>::InOrder(Node<T>* root, void(*InOrderPtr)(T &)) const
{
    if (root->left != nullptr)
    {
        InOrder(root->left, *InOrderPtr);
    }

    InOrderPtr(root->GetData());

    if (root->right != nullptr)
    {
        InOrder(root->right, *InOrderPtr);
    }
}
```

```
template <class T>
void Bst<T>::InOrderTraversal(void (*InOrderPtr)(T&)) const
{
    InOrder(this->root, *InOrderPtr);
}
```

However I am stuck in that I do not know how to proceed next to traverse and find the average of all the ages. Can someone direct me how to do so?

Comment: Please give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Clearly you are meant to create a function to do the calculation, that is what the function pointer is for. Also clearly that function has the signature `void some_func(Person& p)` And that's where the problem is, how can a function with that signature return the result of any calculation? Where can it hold the state necessary to do the calculation (the function needs to add up the ages as it does the traversal)? Now you could do something with global variables, but  doubt that is what you are supposed to do. So I think your framework is incorrect, and that is probably why you are struggling.

Comment: I think what you need to do is allow your traversal function take a parameter of a different type than the type of the tree. So your code would look something like this `template <class T> class Bst { ... template <class U> void InorderTraversal(U& u) const; ... };` That gives you much more flexibility,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the second argument to the BST visitor not a function pointer but a templated argument:

```
template <typename T, typename Callback>
void Bst<T>::InOrder(Node<T>* root, Callback&& callback) const {
  // ...
  callback(root->getData());
  // ...
}

template <typename T, typename Callback>
void Bst<T>::InOrderTraversal(Callback&& callback) const
{
    InOrder(this->root, std::move(callback));
}
```

That will allow you to not only pass a function pointer if you like, but also pass a lambda function with state:

```
int sum = 0;
int num = 0;
bst->InOrderTraversal([&](Person const& person) {
  sum += person.age;
  num += 1;
});
auto const average = static_cast<float>(sum) / num;
```